# conditional casting of variables in C

Tags: c, casting

I have the following expression where all variables are int (and the exercise asked that they must be int)

```
final_grade = (0.85*exam_grade) + (0.15*homework_grade);
```

In the expression above, values such as 82.499 should be converted to 82 and 82.5 should be converted to 83.

I tried the approach below but I do not think that's the correct approach. Thanks for your help.

```
final_grade = (0.85*exam_grade) + (0.15*homework_grade);
final_grade = (float)final_grade;
```

Comment: Sounds like you are expected to use a [rounding function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/round).

Comment: (int)(val+0.5f)

Answer (score 3):

To compute the result with integer arithmetic, let the percentage for the exam grade be `PE` (*e.g.*, 85) and the percentage for the homework grade be `PH`. Then the rounded score is:

```
(PE*exam_grade + PH*homework_grade + 50) / 100
```

Computing the result with floating-point arithmetic runs the risk that, due to errors in floating-point arithmetic, the fraction before rounding will be slightly below .5 even though the mathematical result computed with real-arithmetic would be exactly .5, and thus the result after rounding will be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Assuming the final_grade variable is int.

```
#include <math.h>
int final_grade = round((0.85*exam_grade) + (0.15*homework_grade));
```

A simple type cast will just remove the decimal part of the answer and then keep the integer part. 
But round function rounds the part to the nearest floating-point and then you can convert it to an integer. 
for more information see [this.](https://fresh2refresh.com/c-programming/c-arithmetic-functions/c-round-function/)

Comment: Please elaborate on the merits of this solution. Simply "try this" is not the greatest answer

Comment: The `(int)` in `final_grade = (int) round(final_grade);` has no effect. Presumably `final_grade` is a `double` or other floating-point type. Then `round` produces an integer value. `int` converts this to the `int` type but does not change the value (unless overflow) occurs, and then the assignment to `final_grade` converts it back to floating-point, again with no change in value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks for pointing out the blunder. Made changes

Comment: This code produces incorrect results. Suppose `exam_grade` is 31, `homework_grade` is 1, and IEEE-754 binary64 is in use. Then `(0.85*exam_grade) + (0.15*homework_grade)` produces 5.49999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375, from which `round` produces 5, but the desired result is 6.

Comment: @EricPostpischil in the question it has been mentioned that 82.49 should be rounded to 82 only. Which is the correct expected behavior of the round function.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh: But the mathematical result using correct real-number arithmetic is **not** 5.49999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375. It is 5.5, and that should be rounded to 6. This code has errors in the arithmetic before the rounding occurs.

Comment: @EricPostpischil what should then be done? This is more of an error in the library itself rather than the code. But since I'm not sure what to do here could you please suggest an alternative.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh: It is not an error in the library; it is not an error in the `round` function. It is a hazard of using floating-point arithmetic. As my answer shows, correct results can easily be computed using integer arithmetic.

Comment: @ApurvaSingh. Thanks. I just tried and it worked. But is there a way to make it work with casting without using the math.h library?

Comment: @ApurvaSingh. From the link that you attached it says the round function returns integer value less than the argument if decimal value is from ”.1 to .5″. However, the exercise says that values with ".5" decimal are converted to the next int.

Comment: @MohamedNabassoua as mentioned in the comments you can try out with Eric's answer. I don't think only casting would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The following performs the calculation, then rounds it and then converts it to int:

```
int final_grade = (0.85*exam_grade) + (0.15*homework_grade) + 0.5;
```

(The conversion to int is automatic because the lvalue is int.)

Comment: This code produces incorrect results. Suppose `exam_grade` is 31, `homework_grade` is 1, and IEEE-754 binary64 is in use. Then `(0.85*exam_grade) + (0.15*homework_grade)` produces 5.49999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375, from which `round` produces 5, but the desired result is 6.

Comment: Eric, I was aware of the borderline case but forgot about it. Your integer solution is best. Does the `round` function handle these borderline cases?

Comment: There is nothing for `round` to do. When the value computed by the expression is 5.49999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375, the proper result of rounding it to the nearest integer is 5. `round` cannot look at the value and determine anybody meant it to be 5.5 and somehow fix the error that occurred prior to `round` being called. You cannot get correct results from incorrect input.